# Determine load date of rows in netezza

Tags: netezza

I'm a systems analyst.  I'm pretty new to the field.

I am trying to find the load date for rows in a Netezza table.

Is there a standard query I could use?  Like looking up the names of tables or columns (I've done this).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to determine when a row was loaded via metadata maintained by Netezza, as Netezza does not implicitly record a creation timestamp or date for rows in a table. This sort of functionality would need to be built and maintained by the ETL processes that load the database.